# mmap speed compared to read and write

Tags: linux, file, copy, mmap

I use mmap, read and write system calls to copy file. I want to see the advantage of mmap speed.

I consider four ways to copy:

1. read+write
2. read+mmap
3. write+mmap
4. mmap+mmap

However, the result is that regardless of the block size, mmap is always slower than read and write.

Source code:

```cpp
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        
#include <fcntl.h>       
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

constexpr long MAP_SIZE = 1L*1024*1024*1024;
constexpr int BLOCK_SIZE = 256;

using namespace std;

void test1(int fd1, int fd2){
    // read+write
    char buf[BLOCK_SIZE];
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for(long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
        // use for fair
        off_t file_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset-page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset+BLOCK_SIZE;

        read(fd1, buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
        write(fd2, buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "read+write use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
}
void test2(int fd1, int fd2){
    // mmap+write
    char *buf;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for(long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
        off_t file_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

        buf = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, page_align_offset);
        write(fd2, buf+in_page_offset, BLOCK_SIZE);
        munmap(buf, mm_len);
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap+write use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
}
void test3(int fd1, int fd2){
    // read+mmap
    char buf1[BLOCK_SIZE];
    char* buf2;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for(long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
        off_t file_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset-page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset+BLOCK_SIZE;

        read(fd1, buf1, BLOCK_SIZE);
        buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, page_align_offset);
        memcpy(buf2+in_page_offset, buf1, BLOCK_SIZE);
        munmap(buf2, mm_len);
    }
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "read+mmap use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
}
void test4(int fd1, int fd2){
    // mmap+mmap
    char* buf1;
    char* buf2;
    clock_t t1 = clock();
    for(long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
        off_t file_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset-page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset+BLOCK_SIZE;

        buf1 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, page_align_offset);
        buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, page_align_offset);
        memcpy(buf2+in_page_offset, buf1+in_page_offset, BLOCK_SIZE);

        munmap(buf1, mm_len);
        munmap(buf2, mm_len);
    }
    
    clock_t t2 = clock();
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap+mmap use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    fd1 = shm_open("shm1", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    fd2 = shm_open("shm2", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    // fd1 = open("f1", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    // fd2 = open("f2", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    if(fd1 < 0 || fd2 < 0){
        printf("shm_open failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if (ftruncate(fd1, MAP_SIZE) < 0){
        printf("ftruncate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd2, MAP_SIZE) < 0){
        printf("ftruncate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    test1(fd1, fd2);
    test2(fd1, fd2);
    test3(fd1, fd2);
    test4(fd1, fd2);
}
```

One of results showing that mmap is slower:

```
total size is: 1073741824

block size is: 4096

read+write use 254.571ms

total size is: 1073741824

block size is: 4096

mmap+write use 486.342ms

total size is: 1073741824

block size is: 4096

read+mmap use 537.277ms

total size is: 1073741824

block size is: 4096

mmap+mmap use 737.734ms
```

Comment: *I want to see the advantage of mmap speed.*  Where did you get the idea that `mmap()` is faster? It's not.  All `read()` and `write()` have to do is copy data from storage into the process address space, or from the process address space to storage.  `mmap()` has to do that ***and*** create virtual pages in the process address space, ***and*** allocate physical pages, ***and*** create virtual-to-physical mappings.  ***Then*** it can copy the data.  (Yes, you can get page faults with `read()` or `write()` but you can control that.  You ***WILL*** have multiple page faults with `mmap()`...)

Comment: `read()` and `write()` need copy `fd1` data to userspace, than copy them to `fd2` but `mmap` only need build page mapping and copy once

Comment: So?  `mmap()` is ***SLOW***.  You just learned that.

Comment: I do not think so. Comparing 1 and 4, 1 made two copies, and 4 only made one copy and two page faults. But page fault is only to modify the page table. it should be faster than copying data

Comment: You don't think so?  [Well, one Linus Torvalds would vehemently disagree with you](https://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2) and I strongly suspect he knows more about how memory is handled than you do.  Again:  `mmap()` is ***SLOW***.   Note that you saw `mmap()` take three times longer than `read()`/`write()`.  Which is ***exactly*** the same performance difference Linus was responding to...  Plus ça change, plus c'est la même chose

Comment: What I want to say is not a separate comparison between mmap and read or write, but the reduction of one copy brought by the use of mmap.

Comment: According to the letter, I reflected on my own experiment. In the previous experiment, one read corresponds to one page size mmap and one page fault. No data is reused.
For example, I want to transmit 4k data, 4 bytes at a time. In the previous experiment, I will call `mmap` 1000 times to map memory, and map this page every time. This is not ideal, and this is not the actual use of mmap.
I conducted 3 supplementary experiments, `mmap` maps all MAP_SIZE memory at once, `read` and `write` segments. This time, the time of using mmap will be less than the time of `read` and `write`

Comment: Supplementary experiment in the answer below

Comment: I want to emphasize again that what I want to compare is whether the time reduction caused by the reduced number of copies after using `mmap` can actually speed up io, not the speed of `mmap` and `read` and `write`.

Comment: I used the actual disk file for testing, read and write will be slower than shm file. At the same time. I increased the BLOCK_SIZE to the size of 1 page for testing, and the time is similar.

Comment: As for asynchronous io, I don’t know why I want to use it. I don’t know the api of asynchronous io in Linux.

Comment: I think we need to discuss it calmly. If you think my point of view is problematic, you can use experiments to prove it. Please don't use unpleasant ways to communicate.

Comment: You don't seem to realize that the ***SLOW*** acts of virtual memory page creation and then page faulting ***is*** the IO when you're using `mmap()`.

Answer (score 0):

The `clock` function measures CPU time used by the process. It is sensitive to whether work is done in the process context or in the kernel context.

When a thread goes to read some data from a file, whether by calling `read` or accessing a `mmap`, that thread can make no further forward progress until the read operation is completed. The most efficient thing to do is to do all CPU work associated with that operation immediately so the process can get back to work. Since you measure how much work is done in this context, you actually *penalize* a more efficient operation for getting more of its work done the most efficient way.

So this type of measuring actually rewards inefficiency. Work done outside of the process context is not counted, so the more work the method does inefficiently (while making the process wait longer), the less time you say it used.

I think the main problem is that you don't really have a clear question. Why does measuring the "speed" mean measuring the process CPU time used? Why not measure wall time?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't know much about cpu time and wall time, thank you for telling me this. But I used gettimeofday to recalculate the time, but the result is still the same

Answer (score 0):

Supplementary experiment test567

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

constexpr long MAP_SIZE = 1L * 1024 * 1024;
constexpr int BLOCK_SIZE = 4;

using namespace std;

void test1(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // read+write
    char buf[BLOCK_SIZE];
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        // use for fair
        off_t file_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

        read(fd1, buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
        write(fd2, buf, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "read+write use " 
    //      << (t2 - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "read+write use " 
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0 
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test2(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // mmap+write
    char *buf;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        off_t file_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

        buf = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, page_align_offset);
        write(fd2, buf + in_page_offset, BLOCK_SIZE);
        munmap(buf, mm_len);
    }
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "mmap+write use " 
    //      << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;

    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap+write use " 
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0 
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test3(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // read+mmap
    char buf1[BLOCK_SIZE];
    char *buf2;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        off_t file_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

        read(fd1, buf1, BLOCK_SIZE);
        buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, page_align_offset);
        memcpy(buf2 + in_page_offset, buf1, BLOCK_SIZE);
        munmap(buf2, mm_len);
    }
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "read+mmap use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 
    //      << "ms" << endl;
    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "read+mmap use " 
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0 
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test4(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // mmap+mmap
    char *buf1;
    char *buf2;

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();

    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        off_t file_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE;
        off_t page_align_offset = i * BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE) - 1);
        off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
        int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

        buf1 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, page_align_offset);
        buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, page_align_offset);
        memcpy(buf2 + in_page_offset, buf1 + in_page_offset, BLOCK_SIZE);

        munmap(buf1, mm_len);
        munmap(buf2, mm_len);
    }

    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "mmap+mmap use " 
    //      << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 
    //      << "ms" << endl;
    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap+mmap use " 
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0 
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test5(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // mmap(large)+write
    char *buf;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();

    // for(long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++){
    //     off_t file_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE;
    //     off_t page_align_offset = i*BLOCK_SIZE & ~(sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE)-1);
    //     off_t in_page_offset = file_offset - page_align_offset;
    //     int mm_len = in_page_offset + BLOCK_SIZE;

    //     buf = (char *)mmap(NULL, mm_len, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, page_align_offset);
    //     write(fd2, buf+in_page_offset, BLOCK_SIZE);
    //     munmap(buf, mm_len);
    // }
    buf = (char *)mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, 0);
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        write(fd2, buf + i * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    munmap(buf, MAP_SIZE);
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "mmap+write use " 
    //      << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 
    //      << "ms" << endl;

    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap(large)+write use " 
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0 
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test6(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // read+mmap(large)
    char buf1[BLOCK_SIZE];
    char *buf2;
    lseek(fd1, 0, SEEK_SET);
    lseek(fd2, 0, SEEK_SET);

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();
    buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, 0);
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        read(fd1, buf2 + i * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    munmap(buf2, MAP_SIZE);
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "read+mmap use " << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "read+mmap(large) use "
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0
        << "ms" << endl;
}
void test7(int fd1, int fd2)
{
    // mmap(large)+mmap(large)
    char *buf1;
    char *buf2;

    timeval tv1;
    gettimeofday(&tv1, nullptr);
    // clock_t t1 = clock();
    buf1 = (char *)mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd1, 0);
    buf2 = (char *)mmap(NULL, MAP_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd2, 0);
    for (long i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE / BLOCK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        memcpy(buf2 + i * BLOCK_SIZE, buf1 + i * BLOCK_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE);
    }
    munmap(buf1, MAP_SIZE);
    munmap(buf2, MAP_SIZE);
    // clock_t t2 = clock();
    // cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    // cout << "mmap+mmap use "
    //      << (clock() - t1) * 1.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000 << "ms" << endl;
    timeval tv2;
    gettimeofday(&tv2, nullptr);
    cout << "total size is: " << MAP_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "block size is: " << BLOCK_SIZE << endl;
    cout << "mmap(large)+mmap(large) use "
        << (tv2.tv_sec - tv1.tv_sec) * 1000 + (tv2.tv_usec - tv1.tv_usec) / 1000.0
        << "ms" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd1, fd2;
    fd1 = shm_open("shm1", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    fd2 = shm_open("shm2", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0644);
    // fd1 = open("f1", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    // fd2 = open("f2", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0644);
    if (fd1 < 0 || fd2 < 0)
    {
        printf("shm_open failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd1, MAP_SIZE) < 0)
    {
        printf("ftruncate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (ftruncate(fd2, MAP_SIZE) < 0)
    {
        printf("ftruncate failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    test1(fd1, fd2);
    test2(fd1, fd2);
    test3(fd1, fd2);
    test4(fd1, fd2);
    test5(fd1, fd2);
    test6(fd1, fd2);
    test7(fd1, fd2);
}

total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
read+write use 113.286ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
mmap+write use 353.928ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
read+mmap use 355.605ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
mmap+mmap use 602.21ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
mmap(large)+write use 57.245ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
read+mmap(large) use 43.094ms
total size is: 1048576
block size is: 4
mmap(large)+mmap(large) use 0.611ms
```